# Out of the blue sprites of userdata hides themselves

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my game i am having a very weird problem. Sometimes in the game the userdata attached to body suddenly hides themselves but the bodies still show... I am using cocos2d version 0x00020000 and it does not help searching on the net. Problem occurs both on release mode and debug mode. the children attached to these bodies still are seen but the userdata sprites do not

Comment: some context please (ie relevant code)

Comment: well that was a problem that was occurring because CCMUtuableDictionary was not handled correctly... but i appreciate your help... Thanks anyWay :)